# Low volume in mono sound output in Ubuntu

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I am using the following commands to have mono sound output in Ubuntu 16.04:

**Find output device name:**

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep name:
```

**Get mono output:**

```
pactl load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=mono master=THE_NAME_FROM_THE_PREVIOUS_COMMAND channels=2 channel_map=mono,mono
```

The problem is that even at full volume the audio is too low.

[image: pic]

**Can someone please point out how to solve this issue?**

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the field "Allow louder than 100%". Look at the image that you posted above, there is an option in the settings for sound, in GUI.